# Reach dataitem from other column within a kendo grid

Tags: razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I would assume it would be trivial to get the current item from another column when doing a grid.

Try to look at this example. The hardcoded 106 should be the DepartmentId, but I can't use the p lambda, and I don't know how else I should go it using Razor.

Else I guess I have to do it in JavaScript.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Product>()
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Product"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "Product"))
      )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Title("Titel");
          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.DepartmentId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Departments"], "Id", "Name");
          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.EditorialId, ((IEnumerable<Editorial>)ViewData["Editorials"]).Where(x => x.ParentId == 106), "Id", "Name");
          columns.Command(command => command.Edit().Text("Rediger").UpdateText("Gem").CancelText("Fortryd"));
      })
          .Pageable()
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
          .Sortable())
```

Comment: Does your view have a ViewModel? If so, I can give you an alternate solution.

Comment: I can have whatever is needed. For a while I had a view model, or the dropdown can fetch via ajax/odata. I tried to hook into the edit event since the dropdown only appear during edit, but also couldn't figure it out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution with a JavaScript binding.

You must understand there is a hieracy, publisher, department, editorial.

```
<script>
var departments = $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewData["Departments"]))');
var editorials =  $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewData["Editorials"]))');

function onEdit(e) {
    //debugger;

    $("#DepartmentId").kendoDropDownList({ dataTextField: "Name",dataValueField: "Id",});
    $("#EditorialId").kendoDropDownList({ dataTextField: "Name",dataValueField: "Id",});

    $('#DepartmentId').data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(getDepartments(e.model.PublisherId));
    $('#EditorialId').data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(getEditorials(e.model.DepartmentId));
}

function getEditorials(parentId) {
    return jQuery.grep(editorials, (function (element, index) { return element.ParentId === parentId; }));
}

function getDepartments(parentId) {
    return jQuery.grep(departments, (function (element, index) { return element.ParentId === parentId; }));
}
</script>
```

I wont post the grid again, all it needs is the edit binding

```
.Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather involved, but it would be my recommended implementation.  It is also assuming that you have the "department id" or parent id as a route parameter of some sort in the controller layer (you'll see this in the controller action code snippet).

To start, create a view model for the page that *hosts* the Kendo Grid.  It might look something like this:

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Editorial> Editorials { get; set; }

    public ListViewModel()
    {
        Departments = new List<Department>();
        Editorials = new List<Editorial>();
    }
}
```

In your controller's action method that renders the view with the Kendo Grid, update it to something similar to this:

(Note: I'm assuming the use of Entity Framework in this example, but you could easily swap out for your data access method.)

```
public class ActionResult Index(int parentId) // I'm assuming this is a route value of some sort
{
    var model = new ListViewModel();
    model.Departments = _dbContext.Departments.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).ToList();
    model.Editorials = _dbContext.Editorials.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Now, change your Kendo Grid to:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Product>()
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Product"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "Product"))
      )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Title("Titel");
          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.DepartmentId, Model.Departments, "Id", "Name");
          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.EditorialId, Model.Editorials, "Id", "Name");
          columns.Command(command => command.Edit().Text("Rediger").UpdateText("Gem").CancelText("Fortryd"));
      })
          .Pageable()
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
          .Sortable())
```

The only change here, is instead of doing `((IEnumerable<Editorial>)ViewData["Editorials"]).Where(x => x.ParentId == 106)` you can do `Model.Editorials` as the controller will filter out your results.

Comment: If I did this in the initial controller then I would reduce it one time. The idea is that it has to change based on the row, e.g. a product in 1 department have another set of editorials than another department. I wan't different dropdowns per row.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood.  I think the only way to do that is via JS but not sure of an implementation off the top of my head.